# Create a stored procedure in a package oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created the following package in Oracle:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PackageName AS 

TYPE general_item
IS
  RECORD
  (
    item_no item_t.item_no%TYPE ,
    item_type item_t.item_type%TYPE,
    item_state item_t.item_state%TYPE,
    item_name item_t.item_name%TYPE,
    prodname_no item_t.prodname_no%TYPE,
    prod_name item_t.prod_name%TYPE,
    prodname_no2 item_t.prodname_no2%TYPE,
    prod_name2 item_t.prod_name2%TYPE,
    prodtype_no item_t.prodtype_no%TYPE,
    prodtype_name item_t.prodtype_name%TYPE,
    designer_no item_t.designer_no%TYPE,
    designer_name item_t.designer_name%TYPE,
    req_assembly item_t.req_assembly%TYPE,
    unit_name item_t.unit_name%TYPE,
    valid_designer item_t.valid_designer%TYPE,
    sale_start_date item_t.sale_start_date%TYPE,
    sale_end_date item_t.sale_end_date%TYPE,
    short_material_text item_t.short_material_text%TYPE,
    imeas_ref_imp item_t.imeas_ref_imp%TYPE,
    imeas_ref_met item_t.imeas_ref_met%TYPE,
    valid_design_text item_t.valid_design_text%TYPE,
    pe_no item_t.pe_no%TYPE,
    hfb_no item_t.hfb_no%TYPE,
    hfb_name item_t.hfb_name%TYPE,
    pra_no item_t.pra_no%TYPE,
    pra_name item_t.pra_name%TYPE,
    pa_no item_t.pa_no%TYPE,
    pa_name item_t.pa_name%TYPE,
    rec_sales_price item_t.rec_sales_price%TYPE,
    currency_code item_t.currency_code%TYPE,
    base_item_no item_cty_spec_t.item_no%TYPE, --YB added 2014-05-01
    comclass_name item_comclass_t.comclass_name%TYPE); --YB added 2014-05-01


         PROCEDURE general_get_item(
        p_item_no   IN item_t.item_no%TYPE,
        p_item_type IN item_t.item_type%TYPE,
        p_item OUT general_item);


END PackageName;
```

Here is my procedure that I'm trying to create:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PackageName
AS
PROCEDURE general_get_item(
    p_item_no   IN item_t.item_no%TYPE,
    p_item_type IN item_t.item_type%TYPE,
    p_item OUT general_item)
IS
BEGIN
  OPEN p_item FOR SELECT it.item_no, it.item_type, it.item_state, it.item_name, it.prodname_no , it.prod_name, it.prodname_no2, it.prod_name2, it.prodtype_no, it.prodtype_name, it.designer_no, it.designer_name, it.req_assembly, it.unit_name, it.valid_designer, it.sale_start_date, it.sale_end_date, it.short_material_text, it.imeas_ref_imp, it.imeas_ref_met, it.valid_design_text, it.pe_no, it.hfb_no, it.hfb_name, it.pra_no, it.pra_name, it.pa_no, it.pa_name, it.rec_sales_price, it.currency_code, icst.item_no as base_item_no, ict.comclass_name 
  FROM item_t it, item_cty_spec_t icst, 
  (SELECT item_no, item_type, comclass_name FROM item_comclass_t 
  WHERE valid_from < SYSDATE AND valid_to >= SYSDATE) ict
  WHERE it.item_no = icst.item_no_cty_spec (+) AND it.item_type = icst.item_type_cty_spec (+)  
  AND it.item_no = ict.item_no (+) AND it.item_type = ict.item_type (+)
  AND it.item_no = p_item_no 
  AND it.item_type = p_item_type;
END general_get_item;
END PackageName;
```

When I try to create the procedure, I get the following messages:

> Error(8,3): PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored Error(8,8): PLS-00456: item
>   'P_ITEM' is not a cursor

I'm new to this with packages and procedures in Oracle.

Comment: The error message is obvious: `general_item` is the **type**. You cannot open a type nor assing a value to the type. Please explain what problem are you trying to solve using tis code ?

Comment: If I had to guess at what you are trying to do, you want to load the values from that select statement into the record type. If that is the case, take a look at the `INTO` clause in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open a cursor on a `TYPE` `RECORD`. It has to be of `CURSOR` type. So, Just replace this whole statement -

```
TYPE general_item
IS
RECORD
  (
    item_no item_t.item_no%TYPE ,
    item_type item_t.item_type%TYPE,
    item_state i
    .....


    .....
    comclass_name item_comclass_t.comclass_name%TYPE);
```

**WITH**

```
TYPE general_item IS REF CURSOR;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't fetch cursor (probably multiple rows) into TYPE.
Without table structure is quite hard to imagine what type is this field.
Anyway easiser way is to use item_t%ROWTYPE if the cursor returns one row.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to declare a cursor if you want to return a result in Oracle. Oracle have already have it on your behalf as SYS_REFCURSOR.

So your code might look like -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE PackageName AS
PROCEDURE general_get_item(
        p_item_no   IN item_t.item_no%TYPE,
        p_item_type IN item_t.item_type%TYPE,
        p_item OUT SYS_REFCURSOR);
END PackageName;
```

Then your package body might look like -

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PackageName
AS
 PROCEDURE general_get_item(
     p_item_no   IN item_t.item_no%TYPE,
     p_item_type IN item_t.item_type%TYPE,
     p_item OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
 IS
 BEGIN
  OPEN p_item FOR
                 SELECT it.item_no
                       ,it.item_type
                       ,it.item_state
                       ,it.item_name
                       ,it.prodname_no
                       ,it.prod_name
                       ,it.prodname_no2
                       ,it.prod_name2
                       ,it.prodtype_no
                       ,it.prodtype_name
                       ,it.designer_no
                       ,it.designer_name
                       ,it.req_assembly
                       ,it.unit_name
                       ,it.valid_designer
                       ,it.sale_start_date
                       ,it.sale_end_date
                       ,it.short_material_text
                       ,it.imeas_ref_imp
                       ,it.imeas_ref_met
                       ,it.valid_design_text
                       ,it.pe_no
                       ,it.hfb_no
                       ,it.hfb_name
                       ,it.pra_no
                       ,it.pra_name
                       ,it.pa_no
                       ,it.pa_name
                       ,it.rec_sales_price
                       ,it.currency_code
                       ,icst.item_no as base_item_no
                       ,ict.comclass_name 
  FROM item_t it
  LEFT JOIN item_cty_spec_t icst ON it.item_no = icst.item_no_cty_spec
                                 AND it.item_type = icst.item_type_cty_spec
  LEFT JOIN (SELECT item_no
                   ,item_type
                   ,comclass_name
             FROM item_comclass_t 
             WHERE valid_from < SYSDATE AND valid_to >= SYSDATE) ict ON it.item_no = ict.item_no
                                                                     AND it.item_type = ict.item_type
  WHERE it.item_no = p_item_no 
  AND it.item_type = p_item_type;
 END general_get_item;
END PackageName;
```

Also always use proper explicit join syntax over ANSI-92 syntax.